# Connection with ejabberd server from Strophe.JS (through Webscokets) saying "connection...failed"

Tags: javascript, ejabberd, strophe, strophe.js

I am trying to establishing a connection with ejabberd server from JavaScript (I am using strophe from connectivity purpose), but it's not establish a connectivity.. in console it is showing:

```
strophe.umd.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com:5222/' failed.
```

example code

```
var connection = null;

function onConnect(status)
{
    if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
    log('Strophe is connecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
    log('Strophe failed to connect.');
    $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
    log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
    log('Strophe is disconnected.');
    $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
    log('Strophe is connected.');
    connection.disconnect();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    connection = new Strophe.Connection("wss://emample.com:5222/", {protocol: "ws"})

    $('#connect').bind('click', function () {
    var button = $('#connect').get(0);
    if (button.value == 'connect') {
        button.value = 'disconnect';
        var id= 'admin2@emample.com'
        var password = 'hello'
        connection.connect(id, password, onConnect)
    } else {
        button.value = 'connect';
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: `emaple` should be `example`. That's pretty much all one can say with all the code and the info you provided :)

Comment: yeah @JeremyThille, just posted the code

Comment: Ah, that's better, thanks. Are you trying to connect (via websocket) to a different server than yours, directly from a browser? I guess that's subject to CORS restrictions, just like HTTP, I don't think you can do that

Comment: is there any other why to achive this...using reverse proxy

Comment: Reverse proxy in a browser? I don't think so. Unless the server you are trying to connect to has explicitely allowed CORS, it won't let you. You're supposed to do that from a server, not a browser.

Comment: i will check this and update here, thank you @JeremyThille